# How to create a HTML report with graphs for test results from data in text file?

Tags: python, html, jenkins, automation, report

I have a framework written in python where I execute my automated test cases & the result of the automated suites are reported collectively in a text file. The contents of the text file looks like this.

```
Test.Case.001 - PASSED : Device-Name
Test.Case.002 - PASSED : Device-name
Test.Case.003 - PASSED : Device-name
```

These suites I have automated using Jenkins as well to trigger every weekend. The problem I'm facing is with reporting the results in a good format. This is a text file, so junit cannot be used here. I need to know any method where these results can be parsed and reported in a beautiful format with graphs etc. I've been able to parse the results into an excel file but pretty much remains the same.
Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating an `HTML` file, why not use a plotting library, such as `Chart.js`? You can just import it in your header:

`<script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/chart.js"></script>`

and then proceed to make any charts you want.

Check out the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/), they're pretty solid. I also recommend importing from CDN unless you need those reports to work offline.